# openfit php fatal error database error

Tags: php, database

Using easy php and got this error. it sends me to drupal but does not say what to do?

**Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\openfit-7.x-1.1\includes\database\database.inc on line 2135**

googled this and sends me here:
**https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/DatabaseStatementBase%3A%3Aexecute/7**

Line 2135 reads,
$return = parent::execute($args);

Full Code:
Here is the code: Where do I change that in here?

```
public function execute($args = array(), $options = array()) {
  if (isset($options['fetch'])) {
    if (is_string($options['fetch'])) {
      // Default to an object. Note: db fields will be added to the object
      // before the constructor is run. If you need to assign fields after
      // the constructor is run, see http://drupal.org/node/315092.
      $this->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, $options['fetch']);
    }
    else {
      $this->setFetchMode($options['fetch']);
    }
  }

  $logger = $this->dbh->getLogger();
  if (!empty($logger)) {
    $query_start = microtime(TRUE);
  }

  $return = parent::execute($args);

  if (!empty($logger)) {
    $query_end = microtime(TRUE);
    $logger->log($this, $args, $query_end - $query_start);
  }

  return $return;
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that code. The problem will be in the code that calls it.

Comment: What does the parent class `execute()` method look like. Can you post the code please.

Comment: This code is in a class (scroll up until you find it) which will have the keyword `extends` and then a name of another class after. Find that class and the `execute` method and post that code. (The class will look something like this `class MyClass extends AnotherClass`)

Comment: this is the next class up. I included the comments also..      class DatabaseStatementBase extends PDOStatement implements DatabaseStatementInterface {

  /**
   * Reference to the database connection object for this statement.
   *
   * The name $dbh is inherited from PDOStatement.
   *
   * @var DatabaseConnection
   */
  public $dbh;

  protected function __construct($dbh) {
    $this->dbh = $dbh;
    $this->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);